# Parsing a string in C with strsep (alternative methods)

Tags: c, parsing, valgrind, strsep

I want to parse a string, and I use `strsep` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

  char str[] = "Marco:Q:2F7PKC";
  char *token1, *token2, *token3;
  char *r = malloc(30);

  strcpy(r, str);

  token1 = strsep(&r, ":");
  token2 = strsep(&r, ":");
  token3 = strsep(&r, ":");

  printf("tok1 = %s\n", token1);
  printf("tok2 = %s\n", token2);
  printf("tok3 = %s\n", token3);

  free(r);

  return 0;

}
```

The function do its job well, but If I launch **valgrind**, the allocated string `char * r` does not freed correctly (**definitely lost: 30 bytes in 1 blocks**).

I'd like to know why and if there are alternative way to do the same thing, maybe without call *strsep*.

I call valgrind with `valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes ./a.out`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`strsep` overwrites the target of its first (pointer-to-pointer) argument, so you lose the pointer to the `malloc`'d buffer's base. In fact, if you were do put a `printf("%p\n", r);` just before the `free`, you'd find out that you're freeing a null pointer, which has no effect.

The easy solution is to introduce an additional variable to keep that pointer around and `free` it when you're done. Idiomatic usage would be

```
char *r = strdup("Marco:Q:3F7PKC");
// check for errors

char *tok = r, *end = r;
while (tok != NULL) {
    strsep(&end, ":");
    puts(tok);
    tok = end;
}

free(r);
```

Answer (score 4):

I would like to a bit simplify a good reply from Fred Foo:

```
char *end, *r, *tok;

r = end = strdup("Marco:Q:3F7PKC");
assert(end != NULL);

while ((tok = strsep(&end, ":")) != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", tok);
}

free(r);
```

It gives the same result. But it is worth to say that `strsep(3)` stores next value after delimiter into `end` variable and returns current value (into `tok` variable).

Answer (score 3):

The strsep function updates its first argument (so it points right after the token it found). You need to store the value returned by malloc in a separate variable and free this variable.